# Взять переменную из первой таблицы в MySQL с условием INNER JOIN. Не берёт из первой значение. Как?

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть такой конструкт таблицы:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `table1` (
  `user_deistvie` varchar(10),
  `metka_deistviya` varchar(10)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `table2` (
  `user_name` varchar(10),
  `user_deistvie` varchar(10),
  `date` date
);


INSERT INTO `table1` (`user_deistvie`, `metka_deistviya`) VALUES
  ('111', '1'),
  ('222', '1'),
  ('333', '1'),
  ('444', '2'),
  ('555', '2'),
  ('666', '1'),
  ('777', '2');

  INSERT INTO `table2` (`user_name`, `user_deistvie`, `date`) VALUES
  ('vasya', '111', '2019-09-07'),
  ('petya', '222', '2019-09-08'),
  ('john', '444', '2019-09-10'),
  ('kolobok', '555', '2019-09-11'),
  ('putin', '666', '2019-09-08'),
  ('tagil', '888', '2019-09-08'),
  ('spongebob', '777', '2019-09-08');
```

Запрос делаю такой:

```sql
SELECT t1.user_deistvie 
FROM table1 AS t1 
INNER JOIN table2 AS t2
ON t1.user_deistvie = t2.user_deistvie
WHERE '2019-09-09' >= t2.date AND t1.metka_deistviya = '1'
```

Выводит только 111, 222 и 666 ... Это верно, но необходимо чтобы ещё вывело 333, то есть значение которого нет во второй таблице.

Вот пример работы данного кода - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e79cd9/2

Как поправить запрос? Спасибо

Comment: принцип выборки то этого 333 напишите?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT t1.user_deistvie 
FROM table1 AS t1 
LEFT JOIN table2 AS t2
ON t1.user_deistvie = t2.user_deistvie
WHERE '2019-09-09' >= COALESCE(t2.date, '2019-09-09')  AND t1.metka_deistviya = '1'
```

либо

```
SELECT t1.user_deistvie 
FROM table1 AS t1 
LEFT JOIN table2 AS t2
ON t1.user_deistvie = t2.user_deistvie AND '2019-09-09' < t2.date
WHERE t2.date IS NULL AND t1.metka_deistviya = '1'
```

[fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6af53/1)